# Historical notice posts are still listed in question views

Tags: feature-request, search, historical-lock

[Historically locked posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) still appear in search results. For example, [Stack Overflow questions sorted by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) starts with 4 locked posts.

Comment: Directly from the blog: **These changes are currently in the process of being tested and rolled out across all sites.**  Again, not a bug, just not deployed.

Comment: @NickCraver Directly from the blog: **Please report any bugs on Meta Stack Overflow.**

Comment: Yes, keyword being "bugs".