# Do historically noticed posts contribute to reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, historical-lock

Do [historically noticed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) posts contribute to reputation?

If they do, consider this a feature request so that they do not.

A historically noticed question “is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site”. Therefore it should be deleted from the site. We are keeping it visible so that the content does not vanish from the Internet, that's why the question is not in fact deleted. But apart from being visible, it should have all the characteristics of deleted questions: no voting, [no appearance in Stack Exchange search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124742/historical-notice-posts-are-still-listed-in-question-views), [a visually distinctive appearance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124744/historical-notice-locked-posts-should-look-the-part), and no reputation.

*Please read [Aarobot's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124464/show-embattled-deleted-questions-to-the-public-as-if-they-were-10k-users/124709#124709) to the latest deleted-but-visible discussion, it's a very good explanation of the issues.*

Comment: Even if it's treated the same way a deleted post is then the reputation will count under the 3+ score and 60+ day rule.

Comment: @ChrisF, and he has also proposed [86ing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124754/deleted-posts-should-not-influence-reputation) that rule.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - I've just seen that other question ;)

Comment: Damn, these changes have *just been rolled out*.  It might be an idea to try them out for awhile before trying to change them.

Comment: @Won't These changes were obviously rolled out precipituously and are poorly thought out. It would be better to fix them quickly rather than let them gather inertia.

Comment: @Gilles: By that, you of course mean that it doesn't do everything exactly as you wanted it.

Comment: @NicolBolas for some value of “not exactly as I wanted it” being in fact “completely opposite to what I wanted” and “strongly at odds with the declared intentions”.

Comment: @Gilles: The "complete opposite to what I wanted" would be if the questions were permanently affixed to the front page and every search spit them out as the top scores. You've gotten the questions closed, locked, and removed from site searches, making the information almost entirely undiscoverable unless you happen to stumble across a *direct link* to it. That's 80% of what you wanted. The information is as close to being deleted as it gets without actually being deleted. Why does the reputation from it bother you?

Comment: @NicolBolas The questions are [still visible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124742/historical-notice-posts-are-still-listed-in-question-views), and are [barely marked as not belonging to the site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124744/historical-notice-locked-posts-should-look-the-part). That's 80% of what I didn't want. The reputation for deleted posts took me by surprise, and [here's why it bothers me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124754/deleted-posts-should-not-influence-reputation).

Comment: @Gilles: They've already said that the visibility issue is *currently being worked on*. Complaining about it while it's being addressed is negatively useful. As for your reasoning for why it bothers you, that's wrong. Reputation has *never* been a measure of programming skill. Pretending that it is won't make it so.

Answer (score 5):

The blog post you link makes it pretty clear — in my opinion — that things are going in the *opposite* direction. **Even *actually* deleted posts now contribute to reputation** as long as they meet certain conditions.

> **First**, if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days
>
> In fast-changing professions, there should be no shame in contributing valuable information just because it eventually goes out of date – and there shouldn’t be a penalty for deleting it when it does. Naturally, editing to bring an answer up-to-date is preferable – but if someone else already posted a good answer with current information, you should be able to remove yours and keep the reward for the time it was useful.

You make some good points, but in practice, I would be amazed if the team started to suppress rep from locked-but-not-deleted posts while that's going on.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with this. Users post information, in good faith, under the conditions that were originally present when they posted it. They shouldn't be penalized when those conditions change.

Comment: Also, locked posts cannot be voted on. :)